# Modify greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

It create links to files, that I then can save. But the issue is, file default name always bunch of id numbers, but I want it to be replaced with text content from certain area of the website.
Here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     SC Download helper
// @include  *://*.somesite.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version  3
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @run-at   document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addLinks(jNode){
    for (var i = 0, len = jNode.length; i < len; i++){
       var title
       var id = jNode[i].parentNode.parentNode
       if(jNode[i].className=='video-title'){
          if(id.nodeName=="A" && id.parentNode.nodeName=="LI"){return
          }else{
             title=jNode[i].innerHTML
             id=id.rel}
       }else if(jNode[i].className=='vr-video-title'){
          title=jNode[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML
          id=id.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.rel
       }else{
          title=jNode[i].innerHTML
          id=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[12].innerHTML.match('content_id="(.*)"')[1]}
       jNode[i].innerHTML+='<a download="'+ title.trim() +' ('+ id +').mp4" href=http://d3qx1p4lbtwbt8.cloudfront.net/encoded/'+ id +'_mp4_best.mp4?e=1497022873&h='+ id +'><img src=https://i.imgur.com/5hEBJ2N.png></a>'
    }
}

waitForKeyElements('div.video-title, div.vr-video-title, h1.page-title.video-title', addLinks)
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Where do you want to get the text that you want to use for filename? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to modify last part of the code, so if I press "save as", it atleast set different default filename. Can I make it to set default name of the file as "1", for example? But Ideally I want default filename to be picked from certain text area on the page.